# How do multiple property reads and writes to the same control work in LabVIEW?

Tags: labview

[image]

What is the value of the Numeric and Result when the program is ending?
I can't understand why the answer is 12(Numeric), and 11(Result).

Why isn't the Result `12,10+1+1`. And Numeric is `11,10+1`?

Comment: You can turn on execution highlighting when you run your VI to easily see the values written.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty straightforward. Just label the values on every wire and you can see that the final value written to Numeric is 11 and the final value read out is 12. So Numeric is 12 and Result is 11.

[image]